# overload << and [][] together for 2D vectors

Tags: c++

How can I overload so as to make `ob2[0][0] << 112.6` work? Currently I am using insert function for this operation.

```
template <class X>
class A
{
    void insert(int row, int col, type val)
    {
        ...
    }
};

template <class Y>
class B
{
    vector<int> row;
    vector<vector<pair<int, Y> > > colval;
}

int main()
{
    B<float> ob1;
    A<B<float> > ob2;
    ob2[0][0] << 112.6;
}
```

Comment: What do you want `ob2[0][0]<<112.6` to do?  Something similar to `ob2[0][0]=112.6`?

Comment: http://sscce.org/ are appreciated.  Strip out parts that are not important, but make your code compile and demonstrate work until it reaches the line where you have your problem.

Comment: Please don't do that... Just write a plain function that does what you want to do.

Comment: yup. I want ob2[0][0] to insert o in row[0] 0 in colval[0][0].first and 112.6 in colval[0][0].second..

Comment: i know its kinda wierd but i was practising operator overloading and saw this kind of code somewhere so just wanted to try it

Comment: @TilakRajSingh Are you saying you want `ob2` to grow as needed?

Comment: yup. I am using ob2 to save values in data members of ob1 and to increase or decrease size of vectors as needed

Comment: @TilakRajSingh It's not clear to me when it would *decrease as needed*.

Comment: decrease when i want to delete some values from the vectors

Comment: Consider editing your question so your specific question is clear.  I can't tell if you're asking how to make `obj[0][0]` grow the dimensions of the object, make `<<` act like `=`, or implement a delete function.

Comment: currently i am using ob2.insert(row,col,value) to insert values in colval[row][col], Instead of this i wish to use ob2[row][col]<<value.

Comment: But when you do `obj2[0][0] << x` *where* exactly is this `x` value going into?

Comment: i am having vector<vector<pair<int,Y> > >colval for template<class Y>class B. when I write ob2[0][0]<<x; x is going into colval[0][0].second i.e. into the second variable of pair of colval

Answer (score 1):

Use a proxy object:

```
class A
{
    // provide operator << for a single row/column
    struct cell_proxy
    {
        void operator<<(float value) const
        {
            target->insert(row, col, value);
        }

        A* target;
        size_t row;
        size_t col;
    };

    // provide access to elements of a single row
    struct row_proxy
    {
        cell_proxy operator[](size_t col)
        {
            cell_proxy res = {target, row, col};
            return res;
        }

        A* target;
        size_t row;
    };

    row_proxy operator[](size_t row)
    {
        row_proxy res = {this, row};
        return res;
    }
};
```

That said, you can use operator overloading, proxies and templates to you delight, but you can also make code unreadeble and undebuggable. I personally find the insert() call much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
template < class E >
class B
{
    vector < std::pair < int, E > inner;
public:
    E& operator[] ( int i )
    {
        // resize inner if i is beyond current size
        return ( inner [ i ].second );
    }
};

template < E >
class A
{
    vector < B < E > > outer;
public:
    B < E >& operator[] ( int i )
    {
        // resize outer if i beyond current size
        return ( outer [ i ] );
    }
};

int main()
{
    A < int > a;
    a [ 2 ] [ 3 ] = 1;
    return ( 0 );
}
```

It's a little rough around the edges, but...

Comment: that was just his attempt to solve the problem (inserting a value in a 2D vector) but apparently it didn't work.

Comment: OK. I modified it for the pair.  I do think that the = operator is much cleaner than <<.